# how to make a block completely synchronous which consists of mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++){

if(type == "user")
{   // normal mathematical calculations 
  // result.push(objects[i])
 }
 else if( type == "group"){  
 // Here i need a query "group" model 
  // find group related stuffs  
 // and then push to result  
 // result.push(objects[i]) 
  }

}
```

since group is taking time for querying mongoose schema..so when the objects[i] comes to group section it shows undefined..i need to make sure objects[i] for group executes and the control should go to 
user block

Comment: That's what "callbacks" and "promises" are for. You can't make something which is inherently asynchronous synchronous. You have to wait for it, and do whatever you need to do once it finishes.

Comment: In Javascript, you cannot make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  You just can't.  Instead, you need to learn how to program asynchronously.  You can nest the code into the async completion or you can use promises and chain operations.  We could help you much more specifically if you show us the actual code and make this a real coding question, not just a theoretical question.  Stackoverflow works a lot better with your actual code where we can show you actual code to solve the problem.  We aren't as good at trying to teach a general topic in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Also, doing an async operation inside a `for` loop is likely to cause you problems because the loop won't "wait" for the async operation to finish.  Again, if you show us the overall actual coding context for what you're trying to achieve, we can show you the code to actually make it work.

Comment: thanks jfriend00 ..will update the actual code in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this block sync but only inside of async function. You need to use `async`/`await` and thats all.

```js
async function syncBlock(objects) {
 const result = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  const type = objects[i].type;
  if (type === "user") {
   result.push(objects[i])
  } else if (type === "group") {
   // Now loop will "wait" for result from find
   const res = await find(objects[i]);
   result.push(res)
  }
 }
 return result;
}
async function find(o) {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve(o);
  }, 100);
 });
}
syncBlock([
 {type : 'group'},
 {type : 'user'},
 {type : 'group'},
 {type : 'user'},
 {type : 'group'}
]).then((res) => {
 console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
 console.error(err);
});
```

This example will run correctly in Node.js 8+ and browsers supporting `async`/`await`