# For loop and mysql node how to wait for all queries to finish to process view

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, express, promise

I'am struggling on a problem with node-mysql and a for loop.
Basically what i'am trying to do is to get a Array or Object of

```
---------- ----------
URL       | COUNT
---------- ----------
```

From my database, URL are pictures to be used as background and count is a INT.

**The problem is : Node don't wait for all the queries / answer of MYSQL to process and render the view with the callback, thus, i'am getting a empty array on my view.**

I need to do this inside a FOR LOOP since my search parameter for the query is inside a array like :

```
415 | 416  ...
```

(it's a list of documents id to search).

```
app.get('/next2', function(req, res) {
    function callback (s6) {
        cards = s6;
        res.render('step2.ejs', {
            DocumentsNextPage: DocumentsNextPage,
            cards: cards
        });
    };

    for (i = 0; i < DocumentsNextPage.length; i++) {
        connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT url FROM documents WHERE documents.id = ?; SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT metas.name) AS cnt FROM documents, metas, documents_has_metas WHERE documents.id = documents_has_metas.documents_id AND metas.id_meta = documents_has_metas.metas_id AND documents.id = ?', [DocumentsNextPage[i], DocumentsNextPage[i]], function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            s6.push(results[0][0].url, results[1][0].cnt);
        });
    };
    callback(s6);
});
```

Comment: You can try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715229/5361130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since node.js is asynchronous in nature, it would be best if you use async module.

```
var async=require("async");

app.get('/next2', function(req, res) {
function callback (s6) {
    cards = s6;
    res.render('step2.ejs', {
        DocumentsNextPage: DocumentsNextPage,
        cards: cards
    });
};

async.forEach(DocumentsNextPage,function(data,cb){
     connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT url FROM documents WHERE documents.id = ?; SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT metas.name) AS cnt FROM documents, metas, documents_has_metas WHERE documents.id = documents_has_metas.documents_id AND metas.id_meta = documents_has_metas.metas_id AND documents.id = ?', [DocumentsNextPage[i], DocumentsNextPage[i]], function(err, results) {
        if (err){
           cb(err);
        }
        else{
           s6.push(results[0][0].url, results[1][0].cnt);
           cb();
        }
        });
},function(err,result){
        if(err){
             throw err;
        }
        else{
             callback(s6);
        }
});
});
```

async is one of the most useful modules in node.js. Read more about it here https://caolan.github.io/async

And if you are specific about using for loop then try this little hack..

```
app.get('/next2', function(req, res) {
function callback (s6) {
    cards = s6;
    res.render('step2.ejs', {
        DocumentsNextPage: DocumentsNextPage,
        cards: cards
    });
};

for (i = 0; i < DocumentsNextPage.length; i++) {
    connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT url FROM documents WHERE documents.id = ?; SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT metas.name) AS cnt FROM documents, metas, documents_has_metas WHERE documents.id = documents_has_metas.documents_id AND metas.id_meta = documents_has_metas.metas_id AND documents.id = ?', [DocumentsNextPage[i], DocumentsNextPage[i]], function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        s6.push(results[0][0].url, results[1][0].cnt);

        if(i==DocumentsNextPage.length-1){
            callback(s6);
        }
    });
};

});
```